# Non-unary type constructor bounded by unary type constructor

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections, type-bounds, type-constructor

The title is attempting to describe the following subtyping

```
implicitly[Map[Int, String] <:< Iterable[(Int, String)]]
```

---

Type parameter `A` is inferred to `(Int, String)` here

```
def foo[A](cc: Iterable[A]): A = cc.head
lazy val e: (Int, String) = foo(Map.empty[Int, String])
```

however attempting to achieve similar effect using type parameter bounds the best I can do is explicitly specifying arity of the type constructor like so

```
def foo[F[x,y] <: Iterable[(x,y)], A, B](cc: F[A, B]): (A, B) = cc.head
lazy val e: (Int, String) = foo(Map.empty[Int, String])
```

because the following errors

```
def foo[F[x] <: Iterable[x], A](cc: F[A]) = cc.head
lazy val e: (Int, String) = foo(Map.empty[Int, String])
// type mismatch;
// [error]  found   : A
// [error]  required: (Int, String)
// [error]   lazy val e: (Int, String) = foo(Map.empty[Int, String])
// [error]                                  ^
```

Hence using `Iterable` as upper bound it seems we need one signature to handle unary type constructors `Seq` and `Set`, and a separate signature to handle 2-arity type constructor `Map`

```
def foo[F[x] <: Iterable[x], A](cc: F[A]): A                  // When F is Seq or Set
def foo[F[x,y] <: Iterable[(x,y)], A, B](cc: F[A, B]): (A, B) // When F is Map
```

Is there a way to have a single signature using type bounds that works for all three? Putting it differently, how could we write, say, an extension method that works across all collections?

Comment: This kind of type inference is better handled by generalized type constraints rather than type bounds _(as you show)_, because the compiler tries to hard to infer something that compiles, whereas with the constraints it has more information to verify what you need. Anyways, providing extension methods for all collections is usually pretty hard and no sense, but you may want to read [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/customcollectionoperations.HTML)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Just posting a correct link as the one in your comment is broken https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html. So it seems typeclass is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that `F` is set to `Map`, and kindness is wrong. You would have to have say: I have some type `X`, that extends `F[A]`, so that when I upcast it, I can use it as `F[A]` - which in turn we want to be a subtype of Iterable[A]. If we ask about it this way, it sounds hard.

Which is why I personally would just stay at:

```
@ def foo[A](x: Iterable[A]): A = x.head
defined function foo

@ foo(List(1 -> "test"))
res24: (Int, String) = (1, "test")

@ foo(Map(1 -> "test"))
res25: (Int, String) = (1, "test")
```

"Give me any `x` that is an instance of `Iterable[A]` for `A`".

If I had to do some derivation... I would probably also go this way. I think this limitation is the reason `CanBuildFrom` works the way it works - providing matching for part of the type is hard, especially in cases like Map, so let's provide a whole type at once as a parameter, to limit the number of inference needed.

Comment: I am not sure if this answers your question, so let me know if this needs improvment